Enable to decode in-app purchase response data
I tried to implement in-app subscription for iOS, with sandbox testers I can able to purchase the product but in the response getting purchaseDetails.verificationData.localVerificationData which I want to decode.
While decoding it's throwing an error

Unexpected character (at character 1)
MII8kQYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoII8gjCCPH4CAQExDzANBglghkgBZQMEAgEFADCCK8cGCSqGSIb3DQE...

I'm testing in-app subscription with sandbox tester on physical device.
My in-app-purchase packegr version:
in_app_purchase: ^3.2.0
in_app_purchase_storekit: ^0.3.16

I tried with below code
if (purchaseDetails.pendingCompletePurchase) {
        await _inAppPurchase.completePurchase(purchaseDetails).whenComplete(() {
          var verificationData = json
              .decode(purchaseDetails.verificationData.localVerificationData);
          debugPrint("print> decodedString>> $verificationData");
          return null;
        });
      }

Why I'm getting this type of response for purchaseDetails.verificationData.localVerificationData
response is something like this

MIJ27wYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoIJ24DCCdtwCAQExDzANBglghkgBZQMEAgEFADCCZiUGCSqGSIb3DQEHAaCCZhYEgmYSMYJmDjAKAgEIAgEBBAIWADAKAgEUAgEBBAIMADALAgEBAgEBBAMCAQAwCwIBCwIBAQQDAgEAMAsCAQ8CAQEEAwIBADALAgEQAgEBBAMCAQAwCwIBGQIBAQQDAgEDMAwCAQoCAQEEBBYCNCswDAIBDgIBAQQEAgIAnTANAgEDAgEBBAUMAzEwNjANAgENAgEBBAUC

Response should be something like -

{"orderId":"GPA.3365-7685-1898-54077","packageName":"com.inapptest.net","productId":"testproductid","purchaseTime":1658121156026,"purchaseState":0,"purchaseToken":"kgfemgbkacejamjnmafadmnj.AO-J1Oz9_C62j3NyNe4FPFCHpFIZI2KXfm2JTrl4NE7k4x7Elroi49kJln7Ch1J6bFTMvDe2d8rLvRbJ9tugbQR5lM0Ny8_CKA","acknowledged":false}


See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/validating_receipts_on_the_device - The data you have is a PKCS7 container.  If you can target iOS15+ then look for a plugin that uses StoreKit 2 on iOS.  It is much easier to use.
